# How to set 'auto' height in JQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Problem:
I've a box(div) with fixed width but unknown (auto) height.

I need to open/close that box using JQuery animate function.

Problem is (commented in code too) on Open event, I need to set auto height, which I'm not able to do. Can someone please help set height to auto?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7m5Qa/
Code also given below:

**HTML**

```
<button id="open">open</button>
<button id="close">close</button>
<div id="textselector-body">
    a<br/>
    b<br/>
    c<br/>
</div>​
```

**Java Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("#textselector-body").animate({
            height:'100px' //here is problem. I need it 'auto'.
        },2000);
    });
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#textselector-body").animate({
            height:'0'
        },2000);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried slideDown and slideUp ? :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("#textselector-body").slideDown(2000);
    });
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#textselector-body").slideUp(2000);
    });
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7m5Qa/2/

Comment: Thanks gabitzish, this seems even better solution. Glad I asked it here instead of fixing myself. +1 must for something new to me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `height:'toggle'` ? ([JQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/))

It'll reverse the transformation anytime you click on the button though, but if you want only one button, it's the solution.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7m5Qa/6/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var H = $("#textselector-body").height();
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("#textselector-body").animate({
            height:'100px'
        },2000);
    });
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#textselector-body").animate({
            height:H
        },2000);
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7m5Qa/1/)

**EDIT:**

Not sure I got the question right? If you're just trying to toggle it you can do:

```
$(function(){
    $("#open, #close").click(function(e){
        $("#textselector-body")[e.target.id=='open'?'slideDown':'slideUp'](2000);
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7m5Qa/5/)

Comment: Thanks for quick ans adeneo. +1 for sure.

Comment: @KapilSharma - Based on the other answers I think I did'nt quite get it, I assumed you where trying to extend the height and go back to the auto height etc. If just trying to toggle like the other answers do, I've added a solution for that as well ?

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use the .slideUp and .slideDown methods with jQuery:

```
$("#open").click(function(){
        $("#textselector-body").slideDown('slow')
});

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#textselector-body").slideUp('slow')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/7m5Qa/3/

Comment: Thanks Kyle, this seems even better solution. Glad I asked it here instead of fixing myself. +1 must for something new to me.