# CSS animation in a column

Tags: css, css-animations

I have many `div` stacked up in a column. When top `div` is destroyed lower `divs` will naturally come up and vice versa. I want that transition to be smooth.

How do I achieve this? Do I apply CSS animation class to each inserted div? I am confused. Pls advice. Thanks.

```js
$add = document.getElementById('add');
$remove = document.getElementById('remove');
$parent = document.getElementById('parent');


let i = 0
$add.onclick = function() {
  let el = document.createElement("DIV");
  let text = document.createTextNode("Hello " + i);
  el.appendChild(text);
  $parent.insertBefore(el, $parent.firstElementChild);
  i++;
}

remove.onclick = function() {
  $parent.removeChild($parent.firstElementChild);
}
```

```html
<button id="add" onclick="myFunction()">Add child on top</button>

<button id="remove" onclick="removeChlid()">remove child on top</button>

<div id="parent">

</div>
```

Comment: Please can you clarify what you want - it's not clear - what transition do you want to be smooth?  There is no animation in your code

Comment: yes. I want the transition to be smooth. There is no animation in my code because I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: If all your lines are going to be the same height, then I would use a css transition on max-height (or keyframes animation like below), otherwise I would use a [jquery animation on the height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105795/how-to-set-auto-height-in-jquery-animate) of the inserted element / element to remove (use this as then your animation speed will be consistent no matter the height of the content - with max-height css animation, you can get inconsistent looking speeds dependent on the height of the actual content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation can be achieved using css if we are adding element.

In case of removing we need to fisrt add class before removing to start animation and then remove element from DOM when animation is done. In example there is the same 500m delay, of course it can be done also checking animationEnd event in js.

```js
$add = document.getElementById('add');
$remove = document.getElementById('remove');
$parent = document.getElementById('parent');


let i = 0
$add.onclick = function(){
 let el = document.createElement("DIV");
  el.className='test';
  let text = document.createTextNode("Hello "+ i );
  el.appendChild(text);
  $parent.insertBefore(el, $parent.firstElementChild);
  i++;
}

remove.onclick = function(){
  $parent.firstElementChild.className += ' remove-animation';
  setTimeout(() => {
    $parent.removeChild($parent.firstElementChild);
  }, 500)
 
}
```

```css
.test {
  max-height: auto;
  animation: test-animation 0.5s;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.remove-animation {
 animation: remove-animation 0.5s;
}

@keyframes test-animation {
  0%   { max-height: 0; }
  100% { max-height: 25px }
}

@keyframes remove-animation {
  0%   { max-height: 25px; }
  100% { max-height: 0 }
}
```

```html
<button id="add" onclick="myFunction()">Add child on top</button>

<button id="remove" onclick="removeChlid()">remove child on top</button>

<div id="parent">
  
</div>
```